# Error when loading wordpress theme directly as a folder [hosting on appengine]

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

After mysteriously losing site administrator access to my wordpress installation, I tried uploading the theme into the wp-content/themes folder directly.

However, I get the following error when attempting to access the main page now

{"success":"-1","alert":"Cannot write style-custom.css file, you may try setting the style-custom.css file permission to 755 or 777 to solved this. ( If file does not exists, you have to create it yourself )"}

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: In short, you can't. Not directly anyway. You can't write to the file system in GAE, unless you are writing to the blob/datastore. So the solution is not as suggested in the error, but I can't tell you better then that I'm afraid.

Comment: The file style-custom.css does exist; it has to do with permissions. Also, I think the only writing to blob/datastore may not be true here as this uses google's new cloud storage and cloud sql features.

Comment: sure, my point was only that write access to the local filesystem is forbidden in gae.

Comment: FWIW, your error is not because you moved files in via FTP, but because the service running your website does not have permissions to create/modify a needed .css file

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with the bluediamond themes. 
To fix this issue I have changed by FTP the permissions on the file style-custom.css (The correct permissions is 777) locate in the root of the theme "wp-content/themes/bluediamond".

Comment: I had this issue in the Maxima theme. I had to create the file and give it 0777